# @JsonIgnoreProperties not ignoring unknown properties

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON defined with couple of known fields . I defined my form as follows,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TaxInitialForm {
    @JsonProperty("taxId")
    private String taxId;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String Name;

    @JsonProperty("dob")
    private String dob;

    @JsonProperty("city")
    private String city;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state;

    @JsonProperty("zipCode")
    private String zipCode;

    //...//
}
```

I am getting "country" field with the JSON. So added @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) assuming unknown fields not defined in the form will be ignored. But i am getting the foll. exception

```
 "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "country" (class com.tax.vo.TaxInitialForm), not marked as ignorable
```

This is how I DeSerialize,

```
TaxInitialForm taxInitialForm = objectMapper.readValue(notifyMsg, TaxInitialForm .class);
```

What should I add to mark this as ignorable?

Comment: @buræquete yes they are 2.7.5 jar(Jackson-annotations-2.7.5.jar, jackson-databind-2.7.5.jar)

Comment: So `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties` right?

Comment: Might be [this](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/163#issuecomment-29078124) kinda messy stuff, not sure

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize your object mapper like below:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: Having that configuration shouldn't be necessary when you have `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

Comment: As he is doing unmarshalling using object mapper, he have to mention objectMapper should not fail while encountering unknown.

Comment: When your are using jersey for your Restful service, @JsonIgnoreProperties will come to the picture.Like when your restful application need few of the values from request body.

Comment: This is a global setting, not the same as what OP explicitly needs, maybe he needs fail on unknown on other objects, but not on `TaxInitialForm` only.